Can a button have an info icon within it for the purpose of a tooltip on hover?
Can a button have an info icon within it for the purpose of a tooltip on hover?
This is for B2B so it is slightly more complex UX than B2C.

Could you please provide a screenshot or sample design here? Normally no one puts an info icon inside a button but I don't think there are any hard and fast rules for this and technically it is possible. May just differ based on the context. It will conflict with hover state of the button but should still be possible.

I'm curious where this need originated from. Is this based on assumptions or actual feedback collected during user testing? I suggest you talk to users to understand if this is a real issue, and if so, what it is that confuses them.

In short, this is a bad idea.
Having an info icon within a button showing additional information when interacted with (practically a button within a button) can be problematic from usability and accessibility perspectives.

Discoverability: An info icon as part of a button might not be immediately apparent as interactive. Users might overlook it or not understand that it will provide additional details at all.
Touch devices: On touch devices (such as smartphones and tablets), there is no hover state. Users must tap to interact, and the info icon will either obstruct the button action or vice versa, that the button execution will make the tooltip information inaccessible entirely.
Screen readers: Users who rely on screen readers may not be able to access the tooltip content due to the hierarchical nature described above. Screen readers need to be able to announce the presence of additional information and could be unable to access it.

If you want to provide additional information, you should place this outside of the button, but in near vicinity to indicate that they are related to each other:

For additional information on help tooltips, check out this UX StackExchange discussion: Help tooltips and screen-readers.

A tooltip provides additional context for a UI element.
The essence of a tooltip is to add information to an element. If this element needs to be added to another element to indicate that it contains information, it is redundant and only causes visual noise.
An example.
SE question tags are buttons with rich tooltips:


These are the tags with the info icon to indicate they have a tooltip:

In my opinion, a nonsense.
